# How to get updates from an ajax triggered PHP call while not finished?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, event-handling

Is there a way to get updates from a PHP process while it's not finished and it has been called by ajax? By updates i mean flushed output from the PHP script.

```
var proc;
$('#start').click(function () {
    proc = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'execute.php',
        // getData function that will get me updated data
        getData: function (update){
            alert(update);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Lets say we want to get that echo before this ends.

execute.php

```
<?php
$progress = 0;
while(1){
    $progress++;
    echo $progress;
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    if($progress == 100){
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

**FINAL:**

**myScript.js**

```
var strongcalcs;
var source;
$('#start').click(function () {
    strongcalcs = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'execute.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            rpm_percent();
        },
        success: function(result){
            source.close();
        },
        complete: function () {
            source.close();
        },
        error: function () {
            source.close();
        }
    });
});

function rpm_percent() {
    source = new EventSource("execute.php");
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        };
    } else {
        alert("nono");
    }
}
```

**execute.php**

```
<?php
$coco = 0;
function sendMsg($msg, &$coco) {
    echo "id: " . $coco . "\n";
    echo "data: " . $msg;
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    $coco++;
}

header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
$progress = 0;
while(1){
    sendMsg($progress++, $coco);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    if($progress == 100){
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does the "quick" bit of info inform the long running part?

Comment: @nerdlyist can you rephrase ?

Comment: You want to send something that happens quick back to the page. Is this bit of data used in the longer running process?

Comment: Yes, an example would be a loading screen with a 100% bar while the long process (PHP script) is running. And that something is the progress.

Comment: So you want to kick off a process and then send back intermediate status of how far along it is? If so you might want to give that info in the question more directly...

Comment: Yes but i want updates every N seconds. Plus time complexity of the execure.php is n! so i can't estimate how much time this will take.

Comment: If you cannot then neither can we. Not without more information.

Comment: I want to get a variable from the PHP script while it is executing which is triggered by an ajax request, is it possible ?

Comment: Probably can I see the PHP?

Comment: @nerdlyist updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've in the past used Server Sent Events for this (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp). Internet Explorer is not supported out of the box, but there are polyfills that can solve the issue.

I think Websockets do something similar but don't have experience with those myself.

Comment: i think that what i  am looking for do you have any examples to share ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ajax callback when success load file from server..

```
$('#start').click(function () {
    proc = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'execute.php',
        success: function (respon){
            //do what u want to do here.
            if(respon.status == 0){
              alert("failed");
            }
            else{
              alert("ok");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, error){
           //for error handling
        }
    });
});
```

and in your php you can echo what u want to show

```
<?php
  $var["status"] = 0;
  //if(your condition){ $var["status"] = 1;}
  return json_encode($var);
?>
```

for more information you can see on [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: You didn't understand the question this php script doesn't finish. I want to get lets say a variable from it before it finishes.

Comment: I've been update my answer, are you mean something like that? you can return variable as json from php and get it in your success callback on your Ajax function.

Comment: Assume a PHP script triggered by ajax runs for 20 seconds. In thtat PHP script i have a variable called $process. After 5 seconds of execution is there a way to retrieve that variable before PHP ends execution.

Comment: Success triggers when this PHP script finishes which means it will trigger after those 20 seconds. I want to get the buffer, lets for example every 1 second while php is executing.

Comment: can u post your complete script?

Comment: unfortunately no its a big project with tons of dependencies.